# Issues with wget, curl and powershell to download file while browsers work

Tags: powershell, https, wget

We have been trying to automate the download of this file:

https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/Download.csv

We were using wget to download it several months ago, and it suddenly stopped working. We would connect, but then the calls would hang. We changed the User-Agent in wget to copy what is sent in a browser, and that seemed to get it to start working again.

Since then, we've started having that issue again. We're fairly certain it's not networking on our side, as on some machines, Chrome and IE can retrieve the file, while wget continues to hang. In addition, Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest hangs as well.

The very strange part of it, is that on some other machines wget continues to work. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could cause a server/firewall to block wget, while allowing browsers? I've tried copying all of the headers from a working call as well, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you **sure** it's not an issue on the web server side? I can't download it using `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/Download.csv -OutFile .\test.csv` either...

Comment: @Dennis - Can you get it with a browser? I have been able to from the same machine that Powershell and wget fail from. I’m sure the issue is either the server blocks it, or their firewall does something based on headers or something like that.

Comment: Well, the question was about PowerShell being able to access the URL, and I had no such luck :/

Comment: @Dennis - When I use the code you specified, `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/Download.csv -OutFile .\test.csv` I was able to download it. What could cause it to work for me, and not you? Different versions of PowerShell? What IP do you get if you try pinging www.cmegroup.com?

Comment: Something was changed on the server side since I tried? Or something is blocked in my corporate firewall? Hard to tell...